Algorithm for finding a path factor in a graph
A 1-factor is a perfect matching. A path factor of a graph $G$ is a spanning subgraph, each of whose components is a path with at least two vertices (see the following figure).

Since every path with at least four vertices has a $\{P_2,P_3\}$-factor, a graph has a path factor if and only if $G$ has a $\{P_2,P_3\}$-factor.

Deciding whether a graph admits a perfect matching can be done in polynomial time, using any algorithm for finding a maximum cardinality matching (Maximum_cardinality_matching).
My question is, is there a polynomial-time algorithm to determine whether a graph has a path factor? Of course, brute force methods still exist, due to the following characterization of Akiyama, Avis, Era. (On a $\{1,2\}$-factor of a graph, TRU Math. 1982)
Theorem A  A simple graph $G$ has a path factor if and only if
$$
i(G-S)\le 2|S| ~~~~~~\text{for all}~~ S \subset V(G),
$$
where $i(G-S)$ denotes the number of isolated vertices of $G-S$.

Splitting each vertex into two might help!

Is the problem same as this question Partitioning a graph into connected pairs and triplets?

@pcpthm Thanks. I juts read it, and  the answer seems to say that it may be NP-hard. But it has no any resources.

That answer links to a paper by Chen et al.  I suggest reading the paper and reporting back on whether it is relevant and whether it answers your question.

There is a paper by Babenko and Gusakov ("New Exact and Approximation Algorithms for the Star Packing Problem in Undirected Graphs"). It discusses the star packing problem. Given an integer $T > 1$, a star is a subgraph $K_{1, t}$ for some $1 \leq t \leq T$. They suggest a polynomial time algorithm for packing vertex-disjoint $T$-stars into an undirected graph maximizing the number of taken vertices. For $T = 2$ the problem is equivalent to packing connected edges and triplets.
Here is the core idea of the algorithm. For each undirected edge $(u, v)$ we introduce two arcs $(u, v)$ and $(v, u)$. Let the original graph be $G$ and the directed graph be $G'$.
Let us find a subgraph in $G'$ such that for each vertex $v$, $outdeg(v) \leq 1$ and $indeg(v) \leq T$ and maximizing the number of edges. It can be done with the maximum flow algorithm over the following network:

split each vertex $v$ into $v_{in}$ and $v_{out}$
for each arc $(u, v)$ add an arc $(u_{out}, v_{in})$ with unit capacity to the network
for each vertex $v$, add arcs $(Source, v_{out})$ with unit capacity and $(v_{in}, Sink)$ with capacity $T$.

Claim: given such subgraph of $G'$ with $k$ edges, one can build a star packing in $G$ with $k$ vertices, and vice versa.
Proof ($\leftarrow$): for each star with middle vertex $v$ and leaves $u_1, \dots, u_k$ pick arcs $(v, u_1), (u_1, v), (u_2, v), \dots, (u_k, v)$.
Proof sketch ($\rightarrow$): each (weakly) connected component of the subgraph in $G'$ is a functional graph, i.e. a cycle where a rooted tree can be connected to each of its vertices. Traverse vertices of those trees in ordered by depth, decreasing. Whenever a vertex $v$ is traversed, take its parent $p(v)$ and all its siblings, form a star with $p(v)$ in the middle and remove all taken vertices from the tree. Some casework is necessary when the cycle is reached, it is left as an exercise to the reader.
